# Minecraft Forge 1.12.2 - Item Textures Not Loading

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

When following [Cubicoder's](https://cubicoder.github.io/tutorials/1-12-2/tutorials/) modding tutorial for Forge 1.12.2, and creating my first item, the texture for the item will not load. I have double checked all of my code against his code. I have my latest log [here](https://pastebin.com/gdK6ZM7R). I have my registration handler RegistrationHandler.java down below.

```
package notacyborg.tutorialmod;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent.Register;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventBusSubscriber;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import notacyborg.tutorialmod.util.RegistryUtil;

@EventBusSubscriber(modid = TutorialMod.MODID)
public class RegistrationHandler 
{
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerItems(Register<Item> event)
    {
        final Item[] items = {
                RegistryUtil.setItemName(new Item(), "first_item").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.MISC)
        };
        
        event.getRegistry().registerAll(items);
    }
}
```

ModelRegistrationHandler.java

```
package notacyborg.tutorialmod.client;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.ModelRegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventBusSubscriber;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import notacyborg.tutorialmod.TutorialMod;
import notacyborg.tutorialmod.init.ModItems;

@EventBusSubscriber(value = Side.CLIENT, modid = TutorialMod.MODID)
public class ModelRegistrationHandler 
{
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void registerModels(ModelRegistryEvent event)
    {
        registerModel(ModItems.FIRST_ITEM, 0);
    }
    
    private static void registerModel(Item item, int meta)
    {
        ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(item, meta, 
                new ModelResourceLocation(item.getRegistryName(), "inventory"));
    }
}
```

And my first_item.json model file.

```
{
    "parent": "item/generated",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "tutorialmod:textures/items/first_item"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your error log says that it was not able to find the model file of your first_item. Make sure that you have put your first_item.json (model file) in assets/Your-Mod-ID/models/item/first_item.json

In your first_item.json file, line 4 should be:

```
"textures": {
    "layer0": "tutorialmod:item/first_item"
   }
```

Try it out and post an error log too if you encounter any further errors.

Comment: For some reason it's the same reason as last time. I will update the code in my repository [here](https://github.com/N0tACyb0rg/TutorialMod).

Comment: Please provide an error log after trying, it'll be easier for me then :). By the way, is your texture size a power of 2? (Like 2*2, 4*4, 16*16)

Comment: I see that you've corrected your JSON and directory names. Mark this answer as accepted if this solves your problem. If you encounter any further errors, post your error log :)